# Create non-sysdba user that can grant tablespace to other users

Tags: oracle, permissions, users, role

I am creating an Oracle role with Admin option Grants so that user with this role assigned, will not be a full `sysdba` but will be able to create other users and grant them permissions.

What I hypothetically need would look like this - `Grant grant tablespace  to someRole`

And I don't want use this `GRANT SYSDBA TO myuser`
Thanks

Comment: I took a peek at the manual and it looks like CREATE USER system privilege gives you the ability to grant quota on tablespaces. So, they may just need create user.

Comment: @BobbyDurrett This user in question has such privilege, I will try again. Thanks